# JAXRPC Messaging Style and Format

Tags: web-services, jax-rpc

I am a beginer to Web services , trying to learn JAX RPC
I have read that , for the Message Style and Message Format .
Its always better to go with the combination of Document Literal .
Is this true ?? Please tell me when do we use RPC Style then ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RPC-style encoding was used by old web services that only talked to other systems of the same type (i.e. .net to .net, java to java, etc). The problem was that the encoding of data types was never specified fully, making cross-platform usage difficult.

Document-literal encoding uses XML Schema-constrained documents to pass the data around, which is much more robust, at the expense of higher complexity.  It does make cross-platform iweb-services much easier, though.

In summary, RPC encoding is obsolete and very rarely used any more.